# Is there a *free* QT UI testing framework available?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am looking for a free QT UI testing tool for Windows. I have unit tests for my backend modules using boost::Test. However, the UI has more potential to malfunction and I would also like to test this.

The testing frameworks that I found using the search function on Stackoverflow only involve a few frameworks - and those do cost. Also, it should be usable with an LGPL project.

Is there any free way to do it?

Comment: On which platform? On Linux you might perhaps find testing tools able to simulate X11 events....

Comment: Have you looked into [QTest](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html)?

Comment: As far as I know, QTest cannot be used with LGPL projects? Or have they changed this? QTest would be great, of course

Comment: That is a different question. In some cases, you perhaps can use QTest *outside* of LGPL project (e.g. when using QTest internally in your team), but I am not a lawyer.

Comment: What would be the problem with LGPL projects and QtTest exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing / Troubleshooting User Interfaces is a very tough process.

Classic  unit-test frameowrks (QTest, boost, gtest) are usefull for testing non-interactive modules, classes, functions.
When inputs are required, things become much complicated.

You could choose a "mocking" framework such as gmock to "simulate" a user input.

But if your GUI application has many windows, dialog-boxes, gui elements it might become a real pain in the neck.

There is a second approach that I recommend.

I spent years developping applications with Qt. My first applications did not respect any MVC model.
The debugging and the code tuning was very painfull. 
I also made an effort to separate the logic from the user-interface as much as possible.
Just like the MVC model of Qt (QAbstractItemModel).
This way, you're able to test your models in regular unit-tests frameworks.

You can extend this logic to all of your gui components.

Finally, you'll still have to perform "human tests" to troubleshoot your application.

But this is a normal phase in the development process. 
There's only a human resource that could use your software, click anywhere in the windows, dialog-boxes, do weird things etc
That's the best way to find out unbelievable GUI bugs !
Not a unit-test can find them out.

A developper cannot reproduce the behavior of the person that will use your software. 
Because we unconsciously know where bugs may occur...and thus, we often don't click where it's not recommended...

Think about it.

Z.

Comment: I have not said that I do not apply MVC, which I do. But I very much look for also testing, whether a drag&drop works as expected, whether undoing an operation leads to the correct navigational position in my scrollable list, whether a click at some point in my matrix has the desired effect etc. Could that be tested with QTest?

Comment: Yes, you can still do that with QTest. Take a look to the keyClick() and mouseEvent() and touchEvent() functions. That could help you to tune your undo//redo features and drag'n'drop behaviors.
The most difficult is ti write much relevant test cases...e.g. with random() mouse coordinates. You might discover undesired results.

Comment: Still, talking about testing the View of the MVC, QtTest will provide you with methods and macros for testing (i.e. making assertions), but is not going to ease the process of accessing the implementation of UI elements (which are usually hidden behind a pImpl idiom), nor it provides easy templates for injecting mocks to your objects, etc. So, regardless of QtTest (and of using MVC or not), testing the behavior of Qt UI elements is still a pain in the neck.